# 2008 Suzuki Grand Vitara V6 4WD Noise

Tags: suzuki, 4wd, grand-vitara

This is for an automatic car.
Right after an oil and transmission fluid change, I hear a rattling, clicking sound near the glove box.  I also found that the noise is connected to the 4WD lights.  If I accelerate both the noise and the lights disappear briefly.  Then they come back. Is there such a behavior associated with service done incorrectly?

Comment: So you have warning lights on that extinguish when you accelerate?  By accelerate, do you mean that the car is moving, not just revving the engine?

Comment: That's right when accelerating.